# How can I read a password once, then pass it to the cryptsetup command repeatedly?

Tags: shell, shell-script

When i execute the cryptsetup command, it responds with a command line output - "Enter any existing passphrase:".

I want to read this from console into my script and pass the passphrase from the script itself since i am decrypting many partitions and asking user to enter passphrase every time is not feasible.

Command execution:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/LUKS_device_name /etc/keyfile
```

Enter any existing passphrase:

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer relies on the needed Linux kernel feature [`CONFIG_KEYS`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/KEYS.html).

There is a keyscript command intended for what you want available there:

https://github.com/gebi/keyctl_keyscript

It uses the [Kernel Key Retention Service](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/security/keys/core.html#kernel-key-retention-service) (which has been [around for a long time](https://lwn.net/Articles/210502/)) with the command [`keyctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/keyutils/keyctl.1) to ask and temporarily store the passphrase in memory if not already found, and use it for any related invocations of multiple `cryptsetup` commands. It's probably included in most distributions (eg: on Debian, the package [cryptsetup](https://packages.debian.org/stable/amd64/cryptsetup/filelist) has it as `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl` ).

Normally you'd use it integrated within the distribution and configured in an `/etc/crypttab` file like the given example:

> ```
> test1   /dev/sda1    test_pw         luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
> test2   /dev/sda2    test_pw         luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
> test3   /dev/sda3    test_other_pw   luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
> ```

Which would trigger asking a passphrase for test1, reuse the answer on test2 (because its key id is the same as the previous one and the passphrase was already given) and ask a new question for test3.

Now if you want to use this tool directly, not along system's integration, you can run the command and pipe it directly to `cryptsetup`.

**UPDATE**: Put a complete full example that can be reproduced except for the few values which will depend on environment (here `/dev/loop0` and `969933847`):

Create a test LUKS device from a fake disk. **Be very careful** that `losetup` *actually* returned `/dev/loop0` or abort this example:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero seek=$(( 2 ** 30 - 1 )) bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/block.img
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 6.0997e-05 s, 16.4 kB/s
# losetup --find --show /tmp/block.img 
/dev/loop0
# echo -n goodpass | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop0
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/loop0
LUKS header information for /dev/loop0

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      4e 98 86 0b bf 63 3f 68 08 f5 cc 4f 61 ec 8c 19 71 c3 2a 33 
MK salt:        dc ce 7b a1 56 79 70 c5 02 ad ec 4c 85 c1 6f c1 
                af 50 f3 8c 89 b9 a9 3a 02 62 5c 2d 3f 7a 9d 52 
MK iterations:  312000
UUID:           61a3a890-9564-4c98-866a-1216474b839e

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             2467468
    Salt:                   04 82 b5 b7 0b 90 e4 62 45 96 e3 c3 ef ba 6d 66 
                            1d 93 6b e0 e9 03 40 3d 39 b9 fe 2c 6f 9e 46 e4 
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

Now try operations on it using `decrypt_keyctl`. The prassphrase is as previously set: `goodpass`. Note that `/etc/crypttab` is not used nor needed for this example run directly (on Debian 9's modified version, here with two variables to avoid an harmless warning and still print a cosmetic "example" when used outside of the expected environment):

```
# echo -n securepass > /tmp/newkey
# export CRYPTTAB_TRIED=0 CRYPTTAB_SOURCE=example
# /lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl lazy | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 test1
Caching passphrase for example:  ********
# cryptsetup close test1
# cryptsetup status test1
/dev/mapper/test1 is inactive.
# /lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl lazy | cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/loop0 /tmp/newkey
Using cached passphrase for example.
# /lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl lazy | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 test1
Using cached passphrase for example.
# cryptsetup status test1
/dev/mapper/test1 is active.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  device:  /dev/loop0
  loop:    /tmp/block.img
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    2093056 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

Of course you could even use directly `keyctl`, here's a following (really bad) example still using the previous luks device, that can be done right after:

```
# cryptsetup close test1
# echo -n goodpass | keyctl padd user lazy @u
969933847
# keyctl timeout 969933847 120
# keyctl pipe 969933847 | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 test1 && echo OK
OK
# keyctl pipe 969933847 | cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/loop0 /tmp/newkey && echo OK
OK
# keyctl clear @u
```

Cleanup:

```
# cryptsetup close test1
# losetup -d /dev/loop0    
# rm /tmp/block.img
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but for some reason it doesnt work for me-

[root@vsr-a etc]# export CRYPTTAB_TRIED=0 CRYPTTAB_SOURCE=xyz
[root@vsr-a etc]# /lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl lazy | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md199p9 xyz
Device xyz already exists.


[root@vsr-a scripts]# cat /etc/crypttab
xyz UUID=abc test_pw: luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl

Comment: cryptsetup tells you you *already* opened /dev/md199p9 . close it first (if it's not in use of course) or do an other operation (eg luksAddKey). In crypttab for each line the first 2 parameters are of course always different, the common parameter is the 3rd, and can be anything (its `:` makes no sense here)

Comment: I revised my answer to have a **full** example that you should try